For a practitioner, should I spend time to study convex optimization solver algorithms at all
Sorry this might be a really brave question. I genuinely wonder, is there a point for a practitioner to study convex optimization algorithms at all?
It seems like so many algorithms are just easily obtainable, and there is no way I can write my own solver to beat it. Boyd and Vandenberghe's classic just put algorithms in the last section. And their lecture notes just touch the algorithm in the late lectures. There are even comments that duality theory isn't that important for an introductory textbook at all.
That gives me a feeling that perhaps as a practitioner, i'm better off just focusing on the problem setup and use the solver as a black box, than spending too much time studying the algorithms?

The way I tell my CS students is that knowing the algorithms available helps you pick the best tool for the job. There's likely more to it.

Your time is finite and your career is yours. What makes sense to you to do based on what you’re wanting to accomplish?

It's a bit like driving a car: when the car is working well, you don't need to know the details of how it works.  But that might be helpful when it's not working well.

As a "practitioner" of what?

It really depends on what you mean by practitioner. If you need to adapt an algorithm to a particular problem then you need to be conversant with the relevant approaches. And I would assert that duality is an essential topic, not that I would want to contradict Nesterov .
